# Can't extract UIImage from CIImage with CIFilter

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cifilter, ciimage

I have this new iOS 8 Swift project and in one of its view controllers I have to set the image. However, I wanna change the contrast of the image using `CIFilter` before sending it to the view:

So this is my code:

```
view = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200))

var lecturePicture = UIImage(named: "placeholder")            
var beginImage = lecturePicture?.CIImage
var controlsFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")

controlsFilter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
controlsFilter.setValue(1.5, forKey: "inputContrast")

var displayImage = UIImage(CIImage: controlsFilter.outputImage) // breakpoint
(view as UIImageView!).image = displayImage
```

Well, I'm simply getting an image, applying a transformation to it and then get the transformed version as a `UIImage` and setting it back to my view.

But I only get an error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost got it.

```
controlsFilter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)  // here you did it the right way
controlsFilter.setValue(1.5, forKey: "inputContrast")       // you should keep the same approach here
```

**Swift 2**

```
let lecturePicture = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string:"https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs4RX.jpg")!)!)!
let controlsFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")
let beginImage = CIImage(image: lecturePicture)
controlsFilter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
controlsFilter.setValue(1.5, forKey: kCIInputContrastKey)
let displayImage = UIImage(CGImage: CIContext(options: nil).createCGImage(controlsFilter.outputImage, fromRect:controlsFilter.outputImage.extent()))!
displayImage
```

---

**Swift 3 or later**

```
let lecturePicture = UIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs4RX.jpg")!))!
let controlsFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")!
let beginImage = CIImage(image: lecturePicture)
controlsFilter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
controlsFilter.setValue(1.5, forKey: kCIInputContrastKey)
let displayImage = UIImage(cgImage: CIContext(options: nil).createCGImage(controlsFilter.outputImage!, from: controlsFilter.outputImage!.extent)!)
displayImage
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71543/discussion-between-leonardo-savio-dabus-and-rodrigoalves).

Comment: Why is the fromRect necessary? It's a high memory operation!